# strftime for options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using this to get a select with all dates:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@expiration_dates, :exp_date, :exp_date)
```

which return me with this:

```
2010-10-21 14:01:38 +0200
2010-12-19 12:01:18 +0200
```

However, i need to convert that result to a format of "d-m", but when I used

```
:exp_date.strftime("%d-%m")
```

it returns an error obviously, because it is a string object which I treat as a time object.
How can I convert the value and display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a method in your model, you can call it in the options_from_collection_for_select, so:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@expiration_dates, :exp_date, :exp_date_label)
```

in your model:

```
def exp_date_label
  exp_date.strftime("%d-%m")
end
```